# Problem with separation between items and numeration

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to generate a list with sublists using russian letter with no separation between the items. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle} %,twoside Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
\RequirePackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\russian@alph}{щ}
%\AddEnumerateCounter{\Asbuk}{\@Asbuk}{Ы}
%\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\@asbuk}{ы}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\asbuk*),ref=\asbuk*,noitemsep]
\item Геометрические характеристики:
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
    \item $S$ - площадь крыла;\\
\end{enumerate}
\item Атмосферные характеристики:
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
    \item $\rho$ - плотность воздуха;\\
    \item $a$ - скорость звука;\\
\end{enumerate}
\item Лётные характеристики:
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
    \item $H$ - высота полёта;\\
    \item $V_{max}$ - максимальная скорость полёта;\\
    \item $m$ - взлётная масса.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Should look like:

[image]

But this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: This is a solution for a single list. I would like to declare this in the preamble- It is possible? Also I still have the separation.

Comment: I mean, the other way around. I do not want double spacing, instead  I need to reduced it like in you first comment. I'm getting the second image, that is the problem.

Comment: As I said, with your code I get no extra separation. Do you get it with *that* code?

Comment: Yes, I also checked again right now in order to realize if I made a mistake when posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid `\\` at the end of items. The command `\\` has very rare usage outside of environments where it *should* be used to explicitly end lines, such as `tabular` or `flushleft`.

That's the cause of your issue.

You also probably want *all* your `enumerate` to follow the same style, so I suggest using `\setlist`.

I also fixed `V_{max}` to `V_{\mathrm{max}}`.

```latex
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle} %,twoside Usado en latex-ssau-gost-style-master
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\russian@alph}{щ}
%\AddEnumerateCounter{\Asbuk}{\@Asbuk}{Ы}
%\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\@asbuk}{ы}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\asbuk*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\arabic*)}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Геометрические характеристики:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $S$ - площадь крыла;
\end{enumerate}
\item Атмосферные характеристики:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\rho$ - плотность воздуха;
    \item $a$ - скорость звука;
\end{enumerate}
\item Лётные характеристики:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item $H$ - высота полёта;
    \item $V_{\mathrm{max}}$ - максимальная скорость полёта;
    \item $m$ - взлётная масса.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thats what Im talking about, from now I'll try to avoid the use '\\' in the those envirinment, that recommendation also apply to 'equation' environments?